# Set row height initially when editing a datagridview cell

Tags: datagridview

I'm using VS 2012 and .NET 4.  I have a datagridview control with 3 columns and column 2 (last column) editable.  I have editOnEnter set.  I have Multiline set to true for the specific column.  I have the grid AutoSizeRowsMode set to AllCells.  The above gives me almost everything I need.  However, I want to adjust the row height that contains the cell I am editing so that I can see more than 1 line of text.  The height should be set initially when I begin the edit and does not have to change as I key in more data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're looking to adjust the row height to allow for a second line of data, but only when you begin editing a cell?

If that's the case try putting this is your CellBeginEdit event:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 1)
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Height = NewHeight;
```

This first checks to make sure you're only in one cell (for exception reasons), then takes the selected cell you're editing in and increases the height.

This does what you want but it may be a better idea to just adjust your datagridview to handle the enter key as a newline.  The datagridview should then adjust it's row size to accommodate your data given your current settings.

Comment: I think your suggestion is good however it did not work for me.  I walked through code in the debugger and attempts to change the value of height are rejected.  It almost looks like a readonly property.  I believe one of my grid settings are preventing this.  Most likely autoSizeRowsMode.

Comment: Yea, it's AutoSizeRowsMode.  But I need this set so rows correctly size based on data previously entered by the user.  BTW, I do handle the ENTER key correctly.  I get a CR character instead of the default which moves cursor to the next row.

Comment: I'm a little confused now at what your looking to do but maybe you should try parsing the string entered in the cell, and programatically insert a newline character at the first space after X number of chars.  As far as I know, the only way to expand a row to allow for multiple lines of text is with the newline character.

Comment: Well, still not working the way I want, guess I'm left with manipulating autoSizeRowsMode back and forth programmatically.

Comment: I good with enter key functionality.  That's not what I'm struggling with.  When I hit the enter key I get a new line the way I want.

Comment: Just to complete this.  I had to set autoSizeRowsMode to none.  This was the key.